# javascript how "error" as a parameter

Tags: javascript

```
downloadPhoto('http://coolcats.com/cat.gif', handlePhoto)

function handlePhoto (error, photo) {
     if (error) console.error('Download error!', error)
     else console.log('Download finished', photo)
}

console.log('Download started')
```

I know handlePhoto as a callback passed into downloadPhoto, but I'm confused with handlePhoto function itself, the first parameter is error, is that means js recognize it as an error? can I use "err" replace or other parameter name.And what is the second parameter in console.log means, I can't find exactly answer for it yet.

Comment: You can name parameters whatever you want. It just means that somewhere inside of `downloadPhoto`, it's essentially calling `handlePhoto(mightBeAnError, photoData)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When downloadPhoto function invocation is completed, it calls handlePhoto with some parameters.
According to convention ( rule generally followed ), first parameter should always be error & rest can be result values.

```
function downloadPhoto(url , callback ){
   if(gotImageFromRemoteSuccessfully){
      callback(null,successResponse)
   } else{
     callback(whatWentWrong , null );
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> the first parameter is error, is that means js recognize it as an error?

No, it means that when that function is called, the first argument passed to it will be placed in a variable named *error*.

> can I use "err" replace or other parameter name

Yes. You can call the arguments whatever you want according to the normal rules of argument naming.

> And what is the second parameter in console.log

That is the second thing that you want to be logged. `console.log` takes any number of arguments and logs them all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I think if I add callback && callback(error ,result) in side downloadPhoto function, it would be more clear for me. But there is a follow up question here I saw many functions which don't have callback && callback(), how could these function pass parameter to its callback function?

Comment: @Moniv@Quentin@Mike